# How to use IBM Bluemix publish topic to B+B Smartworx device

Tags: mqtt, ibm-cloud

Bluemix publish topic format like this "iot-2/cmd//fmt/"
BB Smartworx device topic is like this "mfg_id/asset_id/topic".
how can write topic from Blumix to B+B Smartworx device.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't without putting a layer in between.

Namely you will need a client to subscribe to the Bluemix IOT foundation topics and republish on a seperate broker with the Smartworx topic format.